# Using Filezilla to transfer files from Windows machine to AWS virtual Windows machine

Tags: virtual-machine, amazon-web-services, filezilla

I wish to upload files from my `Windows 10` laptop to an `Amazon Web Services EC2` virtual `Windows` machine.

I have seen at least a couple of similar questions on `StackOverflow` and numerous web pages and `YouTube` videos showing how to transfer to a virtual `Linux` machine using `Filezilla`.  However, none of the instructions they offer work in my case. I am using `Filezilla Pro`.  I suspect the issue might be related to the `User` name I specify within `Filezilla` as documented below, but I do not know.

Here is a similar `StackOverflow` post:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16744863/connect-to-amazon-ec2-file-directory-using-filezilla-and-sftp

Here are the steps I am taking:

1. In `Filezilla`: `Edit > Settings >` and select `SFTP`
2. Click Add key file. The key file ends in `.pem`. `Filezilla` does not ask to change format of the file to `.ppk`. The key file is the one generated when I created the virtual machine. I assume the most recent versions of `Filezilla Pro` perform this format conversion automatically. Click `Ok`.
3. `File > Site Manager > New Site`
4. Name new site: `AWS`
5. `Protocol`: `SFTP - SSH File Transfer Protocol`
6. `Host`: Copy and paste text from the `Public DNS (IPv4)` column in the `AWS` dashboard display. This text begins with `ec2` and ends with `.compute.amazonaws.com`. In between it appears to include the `IPv4 Public IP` and region code information.
7. `Logon Type`: `Normal`
8. `User`: I have no idea what to put here. I have tried the following:

`ec2-user` (commonly used with `Linux`), `xmiller` (my name used to create the `AWS` account), the text in the `Security Groups` column of the `AWS` dashboard that shows one of my virtual machines is running, and the text in the `Group ID` column when I click on the text in the `Security Groups` column of the `AWS` dashboard.

9. I leave the `Password` blank. Perhaps I am not supposed to?

10: Then I click `Connect`.

I always get these messages:

```
Status: Connecting to ec2-otherstuff.compute.amazonaws.com...
Response:   fzSftp started, protocol_version=8
Command:    keyfile "C:\Users\mark_\Documents\R_on_the_cloud\keyname.pem"
Command:    open "ec2-user@ec2-otherstuff.compute.amazonaws.com" 22
Error:  Connection timed out after 20 seconds of inactivity
Error:  Could not connect to server
```

Thank you for any suggestions. I will gladly provide additional information if that would be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

As you cannot even connect, I assume that you [did not enable inbound SSH traffic from your IP address to your instance](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/authorizing-access-to-an-instance.html):

> **To add a rule to a security group for inbound SSH traffic over IPv4 (console)**
>
> - In the navigation pane of the Amazon EC2 console, choose **Instances**. Select your instance and look at the **Description** tab; **Security groups** lists the security groups that are associated with the instance. Choose **view inbound rules** to display a list of the rules that are in effect for the instance.
> - In the navigation pane, choose **Security Groups**. Select one of the security groups associated with your instance.
> - In the details pane, on the **Inbound** tab, choose **Edit**. In the dialog, choose **Add Rule**, and then choose **SSH** from the **Type** list.
> - ...